# Hide search results depending on field value

Tags: entries, search

This is my search results query:

```
{% set query = craft.request.getParam('q') %}
{% set miniCards = craft.entries.search(query).order('score').limit(12) %}
```

I have a lightswitch field called `showInSearch`. When it is set to `1` the entry should not appear in search results.

**Problem**
When I do this I always get zero results on my searches:

```
{% set query = craft.request.getParam('q') %}
{% set miniCards = craft.entries.search(query ~' -showInSearch:1').order('score').limit(12) %}
```

Whereas when I do the opposite I get all results with the search term *and* the lightswitch field set to `1`.

```
{% set query = craft.request.getParam('q') %}
{% set miniCards = craft.entries.search(query ~' showInSearch:1').order('score').limit(12) %}
```

I also tried `-showInSearch::1`,`-showInSearch::"1"`, `-showInSearch:"1"` and `showInSearch:0` to no avail. What am I doing wrong?

Problem persists even after rebuilding search indexes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of adding the filtering criteria to the search parameter, I would use a custom field parameter for the `showInSearch` field.

```
{% set miniCards = craft.entries.search(query).showInSearch('not 1').limit(12) %}
```